# Property not found exception - second field is not recognizable for JSF?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee

I got weird problem and I have no idea why is this happening, I got class like this:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "clientBean")
@SessionScoped
public class ClientBean implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private ClientDao clientDao = new ClientDao();

private SearchService searchService = new SearchService();

private String tags;

private Client client = new Client();

private Order order = new Order();
```

and I have part of .xhtml:

```
       <div class="form-group">
        <label style="padding-top: 0px" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Tytuł zamówienia</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <h:inputText type="text"
                        value="#{clientBean.order.title}"
                        class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Status</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-9">
                   <h:inputText type="text" value="PRZETWARZANIE"
                        class="form-control" disabled="true" />
                  </div>
            </div>
```

The question is... why I can't set value `order.title`? There is no problem with `client.name` and other fields in Client class, but when I try to set form fields with order's properties and enter this view then this exceptions appears (I got all getters and setters):

```
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/clients.xhtml]
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /clientRegistration.xhtml @112,67  value="#{clientBean.order.title}": Property 'order' not found on type  com.firanycrm.controller.ClientBean
at  com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:111)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:174)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getValue(UIInput.java:291)
```

Comment: doublecheck the existence and correct spelling of the `getOrder()` method

Answer (score 0):

For JSF to get/set your properties you need to have getters and setter for everything, both in `ClientBean` class and the classes it's referencing `Order`, `Client` etc. Make sure you have all those getters and setters, I suggest just generating them if you are using IDE like Eclipse (right click > source > generate getters and setters).

Comment: I have all getters and setters generated by Eclipse in ClientBean and Order class also..